# ¿Cómo obtener cantidad determinada de elementos a partir de la respuesta de un fetch?

Tags: javascript, json, nodejs, fetch, scroll

Buen día

Cuento con una aplicación en nodejs en la cual, se realiza una petición al servidor mediante fetch para retornar una cantidad determinada de resultados, acorde a los criterios indicados por el usuario en el input de búsqueda.

El servidor retorna como respuesta una variable con contenido html que se genera por cada uno de los items encontrados, el cual luce algo como lo siguiente:

```
<a class="productCard" id="1" onclick="dbt('1');" href="#">  <div class="card">
<img class="card-image" src="image" alt="">
<div class="card-infos">
  <div style="height:60px;width:100%;margin-left:-20px;position:absolute;top:0px;background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(255,255,255,1) 0%, rgba(255,255,255,0.7) 65%, rgba(255,255,255,0) 100%);"></div>
  <div class="chip color-pink" style="left:10px;top:20px;float:left;right:inherit;position:absolute;"><i class="f7-icons">flame_fill</i>-46%</div>
  <div class="" style="left:35%;top:25px;position:absolute;font-weight:bold;color:black;"><s>99.95€</s> - 54.45€</div>
  <!--<div class="chip color-blue"><i class="f7-icons">clock</i><span id="clock-93308_a16f75c23bc26d66:fa69fd74bc09e7b0ca610eae02cdc1579fdce26bfe4db6ca0c377a5244">30</span></div>-->
  <!--<h2 class="card-title" style="float: left;position: absolute;top: 65px;color: #000;"><s>99.95€</s> - 54.45€</h2>-->
  <div class="card-bottom">
    <div class="card-author">
      <div>Adidas - Sneakers Black </div>
    </div>
    <div class="card-comments">
        <i class="f7-icons">eye</i>26
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

La misma estructura para cada elemento retornado dentro de la variable con contenido html

```
<a class="productCard" id="5000" onclick="dbt('5000');" href="#">  <div class="card">
<img class="card-image" src="image" alt="">
<div class="card-infos">
  <div style="height:60px;width:100%;margin-left:-20px;position:absolute;top:0px;background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(255,255,255,1) 0%, rgba(255,255,255,0.7) 65%, rgba(255,255,255,0) 100%);"></div>
  <div class="chip color-pink" style="left:10px;top:20px;float:left;right:inherit;position:absolute;"><i class="f7-icons">flame_fill</i>-39%</div>
  <div class="" style="left:35%;top:25px;position:absolute;font-weight:bold;color:black;"><s>99.95€</s> - 60.50€</div>
  <!--<div class="chip color-blue"><i class="f7-icons">clock</i><span id="clock-93314_1dfb51b8cd5d2794:e0bf81892d745864e7a9cff9f614c405e8ce9309ccbda8db840a0fcbbc5e5e9ff86c32ec976cab58f2">30</span></div>-->
  <!--<h2 class="card-title" style="float: left;position: absolute;top: 65px;color: #000;"><s>99.95€</s> - 60.50€</h2>-->
  <div class="card-bottom">
    <div class="card-author">
      <div>Adidas - Sneakers Leather White </div>
    </div>
    <div class="card-comments">
        <i class="f7-icons">eye</i>61
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

En el fetch, estoy tomando el resultado de la siguiente manera (tomando la varaible htmlContent que contiene el codigo html mostrado anteriormente) y mediante innerHTML, se agregan a un div con id search-result:

```
fetch('/snap/searchbar/', {
  credentials: 'include', 
  method: 'POST',
  body: JSON.stringify(searchInputValueObject),
  headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' }
  })     
  .then(res => res.json())
  // RENDER HTML ON SEARCH SECTION
  .then(res => searchResultFromSnapHTML = res.htmlContent)            
  .then(() => document.getElementById("search-result").innerHTML = "")      
  .then(() => document.getElementById("search-result").innerHTML = searchResultFromSnapHTML)
```

¿Cómo puedo realizar para traer únicamente un determinado numero de resultados, dado que actualmente al ejecutar una búsqueda abierta (una sola palabra indicada por el usuario en el input de búsqueda), se están trayendo todos los elementos (aprox 5000 para esa determinada palabra), lo que provoca que la aplicación se congele y/o que sature el servidor externo, en el cual se están realizando peticiones para cargar imágenes indicadas en el resultado?

Lo anterior, también con el objetivo de implementar más adelante una funcionalidad de scroll infinito, y que me permita cargar, por ejemplo, de a 10 elementos retornados por la petición.

Agradezco de antemano la gestión realizada

Comment: En tu backend debes de implementar la paginación de tus resultados podria ser de diez en diez, en el frontend debes añadir un boton de mostrar mas resultados y vas cargando en arreglos de diez de lo contrario la carga tanto del cliente como servidor se vera afectada

Comment: Gracias por comentar @SaulEspinoza, logré controlar la cantidad de registros generados en el servidor mediante paginación, para lo cual se envía desde el fetch los parámetros en la url de page y limit. Ahora estoy averiguando cómo presentar los resultados de cara al ciente, dado que res.htmlContent viene con información en HTML puro.